# String with no spaces needs to split based on pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string

```
number234-456-132
abc235-456-456
bhjklsds:456-133-456
```

I want split the strings as

```
number 234-456-132
abc 235-456-456
bhjklsds: 456-133-456
```

There is no pattern to the text which is joined with the number.

Comment: split on the occurrence of `digit` or `:`

Comment: Is this a string? a list of strings? ...

Comment: List of strings

Comment: Split on `(?<=[a-z])\W*(?=\d)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regex --> `'([^0-9]*)(.*)'`

```
>>> import re
>>> def foo(text):
...  result = re.search('([^0-9]*)(.*)', text)
...  return " ".join(result.groups())
... 
>>> foo("number234-456-132")
'number 234-456-132'
>>> foo("abc235-456-456")
'abc 235-456-456'
>>> foo("bhjklsds:456-133-456")
'bhjklsds: 456-133-456'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try explicitly to match the three groups of digits at the end, and include anything else in the first string:

```
for string in strings:
    match = re.match("(.*)(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3})$", string)
    print([match[1], match[2]])
```